# How to SSH to Azure Function Linux

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-functions

I have created a `Consumption` based `Azure Function (LINUX) - B1`. Now, I need to access `SSH` of this function.

However, under development tools I am not able to find SSH.

I also tried `https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host` That too doesn't work nor
`az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription <subscription-id> --resource-group <resource-group-name> -n <app-name> &` .

Note: [Both the above 2 commands were taken from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I tried to reproduce the issue as I created the 3 function apps in azure in each hosting plan and observed that.

**1) Created function app in consumption plan - SSH not visible in development tools**

[image]

**2) Created function app in app service plan - SSH visible in development tools**

[image]

**3) Created function app in function plan - SSH visible in development tools**

[image]

**As per provided MS Document, SSH is visible on Function Premium and App service hosting plan of the Azure Function App.**

Answer (score 2):

This is unsupported on Linux consumption plan. If you want SSH you should deploy function in non consumption plan, either in app service plan or in elastic plan.

However SSH is not an option on consumption plan you can always go to Kudu (Advanced Tools) and refer environment details or deployment.
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu